# Does the series converge or diverge and how can you tell

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

The series I am stuck on is

$$\sum_{n=3}^\infty\frac{\sqrt n}{2n-1}$$

I am not sure howto tell whether it converges or diverges.  I tried the ratio test and i get infinity/infinity.   When I graph the function it seems to converge to $0$.  I am not sure how to go about this.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The series diverges because it's elements are larger than the elements of $$\sum_{n=3}^\infty\frac{1}{2n-1}$$ and this series clearly diverges, just like the harmonic series.

You can also explain this to yourself by rewriting $$a_n=\frac{\sqrt n}{2n-1} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\cdot \frac{n}{2n-1}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\cdot \frac{1}{2-\frac1n}$$

and now see that basically, $a_n$ comes very close to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$, and that $a_n$ is always larger than $\frac12\frac{1}{\sqrt n}$ and thus the sum of $a_n$ cannot converge.

Answer (score 0):

If you notice that:
$$\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{n-1}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n-1}+\sqrt{n}}=\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n+\sqrt{n(n-1)}}\leq\frac{\sqrt{n}}{2n-1}\tag{1}$$
that your series is trivially divergent, since for any $N\geq 3$ we have:
$$ \sum_{n=3}^{N}\frac{\sqrt{n}}{2n-1}\geq \sum_{n=3}^{N}\left(\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{n-1}\right)=\sqrt{N}-\sqrt{2},\tag{2}$$
and the RHS of $(2)$ is unbounded.